# How can I print file path in C inside Minix OS?

Tags: c, operating-system, system-calls, minix

I have to edit the `exec` syscall inside the Minix OS, in a way that every process created by it should print the program file path + program name:

for example, if I type `ls` inside the terminal, the next line should show me `path/to/ls/ls`
always in this format: `filepath/programName`.

I already managed to print the program name, but I am having problems with the file path. Can somebody show me how can I print it?

here is the code for sys_exec.c:

```
#include "syslib.h"
#include "stdio.h" //I included this library

int sys_exec(endpoint_t proc_ep, vir_bytes stack_ptr, vir_bytes progname,
        vir_bytes pc, vir_bytes ps_str)
{
/* A process has exec'd.  Tell the kernel. */

        message m;

        m.m_lsys_krn_sys_exec.endpt = proc_ep;
        m.m_lsys_krn_sys_exec.stack = stack_ptr;
        m.m_lsys_krn_sys_exec.name = progname;
        m.m_lsys_krn_sys_exec.ip = pc;
        m.m_lsys_krn_sys_exec.ps_str = ps_str;

        //edited by me
        puts((char*)progname);//this prints the program name

        return _kernel_call(SYS_EXEC, &m);
}
```

and some image as reference:

[this is what happens when I type ls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLCYk.png)

Comment: Well the `char*` cast should have felt bad, because it's wrong.

Comment: I updated the image in the post, it is not printing gibberish anymore. the code is still the same, just had to recompile the kernel to update the changes I made.

Comment: the gibberish is because of my last failed attempt to print the file path

Answer (score 1):

I was on the wrong path, the file I needed to edit was `\usr\src\minix\minix\servers\vfs\exec.c`, I was trying to edit `\usr\src\minix\minix\lib\libsys\sys_exec.c`.

Inside the right file I had access to a variable called `fullpath` inside the `get_read_vp` function. I imported `stdio.h` and then typed `printf("executing: %s\n", fullpath);` inside the function.